# Compare collection with mock collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am unit testing one of my functionalities. Results are OK, but collections of result from method are of type `Position`, collection for comparison is of type `Mock<IPosition>`. That is why test always fails, because comparison between the two is not correct.

Is there a way I can override default comparison between collections?

Results are of type Position, which implements this interface:

```
public interface IPosition
{
    char HorizontalPosition { get;}
    int VerticalPosition { get; }      
}
```

But mock collection is of type `Mock<IPosition>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the collections:

```
var positions = new List<Position>();
var mocks = new List<Mock<IPosition>>();

YourComparisonMethod(positions.Cast<IPosition>(), mocks.Select(m => m.Object));
```